# While running android AVD manager it shows error "HAX kernel module is not installed!"

Tags: android, windows-8, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm facing problem in running the android AVD manager. While running, it shows an error message-

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

But I've installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)

my laptop config:

- Windows 8,
- Intel Corei5 3210M 2.50GHz

Comment: After you installed HAXM, did you restart ADB or your computer?

Comment: XAXM installer has been installed automatically during installing Anroid Studio! I did not need to install it manually.

Comment: I have the same processor. Windows 8.1. I disabled HyperV and install Intel HAXM in SDK manager. And after that I'm getting the sam error message. Didn't help.

Comment: It works. But I kad to go to extras folder to manualy run exe file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create emulator in CPU/ABI in ARM, this error only exist for the Intel processor.

If you want to create AVD CPU/ABI in Intel for this process. Make sure you have instaled HAXM installer on your SDK Manager.

After you download it make sure you run the setup located in:

```
{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe
```

If you get the error "VT not supported" during the installation, disable Hyper-V on windows features. You can execute this command:

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

You will also need "Virtualization Technology" to be enabled on your BIOS

Comment: XAXM installer has been installed automatically during installing Anroid Studio! I did not need to install it manually.

Comment: So are you able to run the setup?

Comment: Yes I ran the set up and it worked perfectly without any error !! :D

Comment: I just installed Android Studio tonight, and HAXM didn't get installed for whatever reason. Android Studio did include the SDK and that installer was in the extras folder. I ran that installer and then everything worked for me on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

if you are running Intel processor make sure HAXM (Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager) installer is install via SDK Manager by checking this option in SDK Manager. and then run the HAXM installer ext via the path below

```
your_sdk_folder\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe
```

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7xoPCv3sYs)  shows all the required steps which may help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do to fix this issue.

1) Navigate to the following path:

C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

2) Run intelhaxm-android.exe as an administrator.

3) Once the installation is complete, Run your project and you will be able to run android emulator on your machine.

NOTE: YOUR VIRTUALIZATION SHOULD BE ENABLED IN THE BIOS SETTINGS.

Hope this helps.