# AVD Error with Windows 8

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Emulator:

```
ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [While running android AVD manger it shows error "HAX kernel module is not installed!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718713/while-running-android-avd-manger-it-shows-error-hax-kernel-module-is-not-instal)

Comment: Please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

In current AVD manager you can't. You just have the opportunity to use ARM images which will not need hardware virtualization.

Delete your old AVD, If you are make to launchable AVD to Create a new AVD and Change the arm images.
To run ARM images:

Open AVD manager.
Create a new 'Virtual Device' OR right click an existing image and select 'Duplicate'
Choose arm* instead of x86/x64.
Continue with the wizard.
Run!
Although this is the available solution but still a slow one !!