# Android project throws an exception

Tags: android, android-studio

The following message appears when I try to run my project in Android Studio :

```
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

PC RAM: 6GB

All required packages have been downloaded.

Comment: "CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!". try to install it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While running android AVD manger it shows error "HAX kernel module is not installed!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718713/while-running-android-avd-manger-it-shows-error-hax-kernel-module-is-not-instal)