# After running Android Studio I got "Cannnot launch AVD emulator" error

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

This is the first project with Android Studio. When I run the project, I have got the following error:

[image]

I have installed Intel HAXM installer(accelerator).

I don't see a list(empty list) from "Choose running device" during running project.

How can I fix it?

During installation of HAXM manually, https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement 
i got error:

[image]

Comment: install HAXM installer and Android SDK Tools

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Comment: enable virtualization from bios

Comment: @VivekMishra, Can't enable virtualization from bios. It's HP bios.

Comment: @VivekMishra, This time i pressed F10, then enabled virtualization under System Security. But still got the same error when i run the project.

Comment: @VivekMishra, Reinstalled HAXM after enabling virtualization, no error this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAXM is dependent on your system specifications. And you are trying to run a x86 emulator.

Please check that you meet the [requirements to run HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows).

If you meet the requirements then please look at [HAX Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29842005/4180965) and [Virtualization Technology - HAX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27718796/4180965)

Here are the [differences between x86 and ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416448/difference-between-google-apis-x86-system-image-and-google-apis-arm-system-im).

Comment: It's 64 bit operating system.

Comment: If you meet all of the System requirements, then have a look at the video that is in the link I have posted.

Comment: Can't find SDK installation directory on windows 7.

Comment: Are you sure your CPU supports Virtualization? Uninstall the HAXM. Download the standalone one from here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement .. Then reinstall using that version

Comment: I got error during installing standalone HAXM. I have edited original question.

Comment: As I stated before "Your CPU NEEDS to support Virtualization" ... This is why you will not be able to run HAXM and emulate a x86 device. Just use an ARM emulator. What CPU do you have?

Comment: Intel core i5 4590(3.33GHz), Codename: Haswell

Comment: Follow this: http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/ Just remember your motherboard needs to support it as well.

Comment: http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios

Comment: I have enabled virtualization from bios, still getting same error.

Comment: You need to uninstall and reinstall HAX after doing the enabling of Virtualization.

Comment: Ah, Yes, i have unistalled and reinstalled HAXM, this time i am not getting that error.

Comment: Great! ... Please mark as answer if I have helped you enough.

Comment: Your comment helped me more than your answer.